# Match a string and paste it to the above row

Tags: r, regex

I have a the following data.frame:

```
d <- data.frame(id = c(1:20),
                name = c("Paraffinole (CAS 8042-47-5)", "Pirimicarb", "Rapsol", "Thiacloprid", 
                     "Chlorantraniliprole", "Flonicamid", "Tebufenozid", "Fenoxycarb", 
                     "Bacillus thuringiensis subspecies", "aizawai Stamm AB", "Methoxyfenozide", 
                     "Acequinocyl", "lndoxacarb", "Acetamiprid", "Spirotet_r:amat", 
                     "Cydia pomonella Granulovirus", "mexikanischer Stamm", "lmidacloprid", 
                     "Spirodiclofen", "Pyrethrine"),
                desc = LETTERS[1:20])
```

The **name** column contains two entries of the string 'stamm'. Id' like to select these entries and paste them to the one column entry before and then delete this row. So `df$name[9]` should finally look like this `Bacillus thuringiensis subspecies__aizawai Stamm AB` and `df$name[16]` as follows: `Cydia pomonella Granulovirus__mexikanischer Stamm`. `d$name[c(10,17]` should then be deleted.

How can I match a string and paste it to the row above?

Comment: I think `df$name[9]` should be `"Bacillus thuringiensis subspecies__aizawai Stamm AB`, right ?

Comment: you're right, copy paste mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this ?

```
library(stringr)
d$name <- as.character(d$name)
where_stamm <- which(str_detect(d$name, "Stamm") == TRUE)
for (i in where_stamm) {
  d$name[i-1] <- paste(d$name[i-1], d$name[i], sep = '__')
}
d <- d[-where_stamm, ] 

> d$name[9]
[1] "Bacillus thuringiensis subspecies__aizawai Stamm AB"
> d$name[15]
[1] "Cydia pomonella Granulovirus__mexikanischer Stamm"
```

(note that "Cydia pomonella...." will now be at position 15, since we deleted row 10)

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking way too complicated. Just grep the indexes and loop through them!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
  mutate(
    to_delete = grepl("stamm", name, ignore.case = TRUE),
    name = if_else(lead(to_delete, default = FALSE), paste(name, lead(name), sep = "__"), 
                   as.character(name))
  ) %>% 
  filter(!to_delete) %>%
  select(- to_delete)
#    id                                                name desc
# 1   1                         Paraffinole (CAS 8042-47-5)    A
# 2   2                                          Pirimicarb    B
# 3   3                                              Rapsol    C
# 4   4                                         Thiacloprid    D
# 5   5                                 Chlorantraniliprole    E
# 6   6                                          Flonicamid    F
# 7   7                                         Tebufenozid    G
# 8   8                                          Fenoxycarb    H
# 9   9 Bacillus thuringiensis subspecies__aizawai Stamm AB    I
# 10 11                                     Methoxyfenozide    K
# 11 12                                         Acequinocyl    L
# 12 13                                          lndoxacarb    M
# 13 14                                         Acetamiprid    N
# 14 15                                     Spirotet_r:amat    O
# 15 16   Cydia pomonella Granulovirus__mexikanischer Stamm    P
# 16 18                                        lmidacloprid    R
# 17 19                                       Spirodiclofen    S
# 18 20                                          Pyrethrine    T
```